# monotouch layer

Tags: xamarin.ios, layer

i am new to monotouch and iOS development environment.
I read Quartz 2D programming guide but I still don't know if it is possible to draw 2 layers on the screen, first layer will be always on the top showing a star or some shape and rest transparent, and the 2nd layer will draw circles where people touch the screen.

I want the first layer to be on the top always and since it is not changing, it should not be re-drawn.

Where can i find example of this or doc?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at the Xamarin Seminar [Getting Started with CoreGraphics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNxVMYKaZP0&list=PL35E8B636BEC8411D&context=C3dd5e8eADOEgsToPDskKXtJdk_pmgW6xcxVUiHFjQ) also a couple of books which have a really nice section of CoreGraphics

- [Developing C# Apps for iPhone and iPad using MonoTouch iOS Apps
  Development for .NET Developers](http://www.apress.com/9781430231745)
- [Learning MonoTouch: A Hands-On Guide to Building iOS Applications with C# and .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321719921)

And a lot of Objective-c examples that you can find on the web, they are quite easy to implement on c# because the exposed API is quite similar.

Hope this helps to get you started.

Alex

Comment: i watched the seminar but it didn't help me much in this particular question. I am reading programming guide for iOS and so far all i found was to add view in appropriate order. Seems like that is the only solution  ih ave

Comment: Oh my answer is focused to get you started with iOS, CoreGraphics and MonoTouch  ecosystem, so you can find your way to achieve what you want =) Good Luck!!